# Is the resolution order of promises same as the order in which it is mentioned in Promise.settle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have 2 promises that should settle before I return a response to the client.

I am using bluebird.

```
Promise
    .settle([prmoise1(), promise2()])
    .then(function(results){
        results.forEach(function(result){
           if(result.isFulfilled()){
             console.log(result);
           }
        });
    });
```

What is the resolution order of promises?
Is promise1() always resolved first in this case?
If not, how do we access the result associated with a promise()?

Comment: What version of bluebird are you using? I don't see .settle in the docs.

Comment: I am using version 2.10.2

Comment: @HurricaneHamilton - `Promise.settle()` was removed in the latest version of Bluebird (to my disappointment).  Apparently, you have to use `.reflect()` somehow to simulate what we used to do with `Promise.settle()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, your two promise generated functions are called one after another and they will complete in whatever order their natural timing causes them to complete in.  If `promise2()` is a very fast async operation, it could very well complete before `promise1()` does and thus is would resolve it's promise before the other one.  Or, it could very well be vice versa.  In other words, there is no guarantee as it depends entirely on the timing of each async operation.  When running async operations this way, you are running them in parallel (both in flight at the same time).

The results array that `Promise.settle()` generates will always be in the originally specified order just like with `Promise.all()` so the first item in the `Promise.settle(...).then(function(results) {})` results array will always belong to `promise1()` and the second to `promise2()`.

Note: `Promise.settle()` appears to have been removed from the latest version of Bluebird.  You can use `.reflect()` on each geneated promise to simulate this behavior as described [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html).  In fact, in the newest version of Bluebird, you would do this:

```
Promise.all([promise1().reflect(), promise2().reflect()]).then(function(results){
    results.forEach(function(result){
       if(result.isFulfilled()){
         console.log(result);
       }
    });
});
```

---

In the newest Bluebird, you can make your own `Promise.settle()` that works with an array of promises:

```
Promise.settle = function(array) {
    var reflects = [];
    if (array) {
        reflects = array.map(function(item) {
            // if it's a promise with .reflect(), call `.reflect()`
            if (typeof item.then === "function" && typeof item.reflect === "function") {
                return item.reflect();
            } else {
               // cast into a promise and call .reflect()
               return Promise.resolve(item).reflect();
            }
        });
    }
    return Promise.all(reflects);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, like in `.all()`, all actions are called simultaneously* and the promises resolve whenever.

However, the `results` array will always be in the order of the original array of promises, so `results[0]` will be the result of `promise1()`.

<sub>* They're called one after another, but we don't wait for the first to finish to start the second</sub>